# Using CSS with Express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am trying to get my CSS links to work on my localhost. Right now the Index.html will show in plain text on my server. None of the styling included. Tried the express middleware, but it's still not serving the file. I get a 404 for the CSS files. Below is my code:

**App.js:**

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Public')));
```

**Index.html:**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/switchery.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/switchery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

//EDIT//

I was setting up the argument for path.join incorrectly. Thanks for all of the answers. Greatly appreciated. Below is the code that worked:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
```

Comment: try: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));` ?

and of course make sure your styles.css is inside the /Public/ directory.

Comment: What is the layout of your `Public` directory?

Comment: @mscdex the layout of my public folder includes three files: styles.css, switchery.min.css, switchery.min.js.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your folder `public` and not `Public`. Don't use capital for folders.

And change for `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: Using `path.join()` is the proper convention in this case. It will normalize paths across systems.

Comment: Yes you have reason :)

Answer (score 0):

As MaximeF said, it's a good practice to use `lower-case`, or `camelCase` for folder names. However, ensure that your `public` directory is properly structured. If your CSS is within a folder inside of `public`, for example, `public/css/styles.css`, to use that style in your browser, you need to include the full path relative to `public`. In that case, it'd be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">`.